# registerForActivityResult is not called in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack

I Recently migrated to latest callback mechanism for registering the request permissions however the latest api for registering request callback is never triggered I am attaching the code snippet can anyone help me to find what went wrong,

```
        @AndroidEntryPoint
class ManageTeamFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    @Inject
    lateinit var manageTeamViewModel: ManageTeamViewModel

    private var requestMultiplePermissions:ActivityResultLauncher<Array<out String>>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        requestMultiplePermissions =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {
                println("DEBUG $it")
                if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                    btnAddUser.showLoading(true)
                    btnAddUser.postDelayed({
                        (activity as? DashboardActivity)?.navToFragment(AddUserFragment(), true)
                    }, 10)
                } else {
                    if (addOrEditUserBottomSheet == null) {
                        addOrEditUserBottomSheet =
                            AddOrEditUserBottomSheet(toolbar.context, addOrEditUserInteractionsListener)
                    }
                    addOrEditUserBottomSheet?.showBottomSheet()
                }
            }

    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {



        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_team, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initViews()
        initViewModels()
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        btnAddUser.setOnClickListener {
            println("DEBUG requesting")
            requestMultiplePermissions?.launch(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)
        }
    }
}
```

gradle dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-alpha05'
```

Comment: Make sure your register part is done prior to Fragment's onCreate call. You can initialize the variable in decleration: private val requestMultiplePermissions = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {
        println("DEBUG $it")
    }

Comment: Its declared in the top of the class before any lifecycle method in fragment

Comment: How many permissions type do you want to request? This is because I only see  one `READ_CONTACTS` permission request.

Comment: Can you maybe add more code? Your fragment class? A Simplified version of it at least?

Comment: Okay updating my question

Comment: Is this a nested fragment, inside `ViewPager` or something (fragment in fragment in activity)?

Comment: @Tonnie Yes only one permission

Comment: No @ShlomiKatriel

Comment: For one permission use `ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()` for mutiple permissions types use `ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()`

Comment: Tried that too @Tonnie For one permission also it is not working

Comment: You need to assign the button and its functionalities in OnCreate() function for it to work .

Comment: Its happening in fragment

Comment: So ? You can use onCreate() in Fragment . I have done the same .

Comment: I tried but its not working I am updating the code

Comment: Try to initialize the requestMultiplePermissions variable in the declaration line. Not inside onCreate. Like so: private var requestMultiplePermissions:ActivityResultLauncher<Array<out String>> = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { ...}

Comment: @gioravered then I wont be able to get it in onviewcreated

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by: "get it in onViewCreated". The variable is initialized before any life cycle method. It will be available in onViewCreated.

Comment: the member variable will not be accessible @gioravered

Comment: I don't know which member you are referring to without further context (code). For me initializing the requestMultiplePermissions in the declaration line works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was that the given activity was marked as android:noHistory="true" in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
And it should be like this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.PaletteAddActivity"
            android:noHistory="false" />
```

Answer (score -1):

just try requesting for one permission like this.

```
private val requestMultiplePermissions =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) {
            println("DEBUG $it")
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                btnAddUser.showLoading(true)
                btnAddUser.postDelayed({
                    (activity as? DashboardActivity)?.navToFragment(AddUserFragment(), true)
                }, 10)
            } else {
                if (addOrEditUserBottomSheet == null) {
                    addOrEditUserBottomSheet =
                        AddOrEditUserBottomSheet(toolbar.context, addOrEditUserInteractionsListener)
                }
                addOrEditUserBottomSheet?.showBottomSheet()
            }
        }
```

Then try launching the request inside the `onCreateView` method instead and just pass the one permission that you need as a String.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

//launch permission request here and pass the permission
requestMultiplePermissions.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_team, container, false)
    }
```

Comment: I need to request permission on buttonClick in onCreateview I wont get instance of it

Comment: Then move button code inside `onCreateView()`